# porting screen shot java app on android

Tags: java, android

i want your help very badly..bcz i am seeking an answer for this from couple of day's but did not find a bit...

my query is i have a screen shot app written in java...i just want to port it on android emulator and run it..i know i have to rewrite some android specific code but can anyone tell me what changes i should make to the screen shot java app to make it run on android platform..
here is my java screen shot app: (i know for this the device should be rooted i am okay for that)

```
import java.awt.AWTException;    
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Rectangle;    
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

class ScreenCapture {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws
           AWTException, IOException {

     // capture the whole screen

     BufferedImage screencapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(
           new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()) );

     // Save as JPEG
     File file = new File("screencapture.jpg");

     ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", file);

     // Save as PNG
     // File file = new File("screencapture.png");
     // ImageIO.write(screencapture, "png", file);
  }

}
```

Comment: **Are you wearing a pajama in your avatar?** (sorry, I was not able to resist this comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't just a few changes that you have to made. You have to rewrite the whole app and that wouldn't be so easy since making screenshots in Android isn't this easy as in plain Java.

For example you can't use java.awt.Robot because this lib isn't included in Android.

Afaik you also need root rights on a Android phone to make a screenshot. I would recommend that you google for librarys or apps that are already able to do screenshots and use them.

For example the Android Screenshot Library (ASL) is a good point to start with.

Comment: can i get the source code of android screenshot app..i have googled a lot but could not get one..if you know any links plz provide me..using ASL i can build but the problem is..in order to run our screen shot app built using ASL a particular service should be made running manually whenever device boots up and  that might not comfort for end users..

Comment: If it is open source then you can get the source code. But I personally don't know any open source screenshot app. However I haven't really searched for it. I don't really understand your problem with ASL. Do you have already successfully implemented a Android screenhot app with ASL, but it isn't comfortable? Or what is the problem?

Comment: no i have just read about ASL..it tells before running our ASL screen shot app, a particular service called run.xxx scripts included in the ASL package to be made runnable manually using windows power shell..but on a real device how can a user runs that service on android using windows power shell....?

Comment: It's beside the point as an ordinary user won't have the necessary root access on a real device anyway.